# Connect bluetooth scanner to Xamarin.Forms App

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth, cross-platform

I want to listen to a bluetooth barcode scanner input events in my Xamarin.Forms app targetted for iOS, Android and UWP.

I found a few GitHub like [bluetoothLE](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle), on how to list BLE devices with Xamarin for iOS or Android (it also says it is compatible with UWP), and some hints as to how to register to input, but I couldn't get it to work...

So I was thinking if there was a way to register to ALREADY PAIRED items (which are paired at OS level, before launching the app) and hook up to input events? Does anyone have some suggestions?